# Accidentally garbled a bunch of file names in /tmp... ssh keys asking for passwords

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, tmp

I accidentally garbled the file names of the contents of my /tmp directory (don't ask) to the point where they're not recoverable.

Since doing so, I'm always asked for the password to my ssh keys (particularly in git). Any suggestions/fixes?

---

**Edit:** Per the suggestion below, a reboot did the trick.

Comment: I'm pretty novice on OS X but on most Unix platforms `/tmp` is usually for easily reproducible files created by applications. Have you tried just rebooting? There may be a file it's trying to find and can't. Rebooting may force it to re-create it.

Comment: Have you tried wiping out the `/tmp` directory? After all, they are _temporary_ files ;-) they'll be recreated and all should be back to normal after you type each password in.

Comment: @lgeorget yeah, that was my initial thought, but I did some googling and came across people saying a `rm -rf /tmp` isn't a good idea. May end up doing that though :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh` communicates with your SSH Agent (which stores your private keys in RAM) via a socket stored in `/tmp`.

That socket path should be in the environment variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. So you could use that to recover the original name, and rename it back.

Alternatively, logging out and back in (or, since this is OS X, possibly just quitting your X server and starting it again) will fix it by restarting the agent. This will also fix any other socket names that were in `/tmp`.

Comment: By the way, `killall ssh-agent && eval 'ssh-agent'` in a shell should restart the agent without the need for logout (using backticks instead of single quotes around `ssh-agent`).

Comment: @JohnWHSmith that will, but it'll leave you with the environment set for only that shell. It won't be set for any of the other shells you spawn (say, from a menu, keyboard shortcut, whatever).

Comment: A good ol' reboot re-generated everything (at least as far as I can tell right now)